# different joomla contact categories on same page

Tags: joomla, overriding, contacts

how can i create a joomla override, to display 2 different contact categories on the same page?

like this

---

Category1-Heading

contact1 contact 2 ...

---

Category2-Heading

contact2 contact3...

---

when i make one into  a subcategories, the contacts are shown only as links, that is not what i need, i just need 2 put different categories on one same page. I think i have to change some PHP in the com_contact. but i can't find which and how..
could anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to copy the files `components/com_contact/views/categories/tmpl/default.php` and `components/com_contact/views/categories/tmpl/default_items.php` to `templates/your-template/html/com_contact/categories` and then change the files there to adjust to your needs.

Note: Make sure that you create a menu item of type "List All Contact Categories" in order to display all the categories.